# Checking to see if a value is present in a list - Apex

Tags: apex, trigger

As a part of my first trigger, which is running on Opportunities, I have a list I created that contains the result of a SOQL query. Here is the code.

```
List<Custom_Object__c> mylist = [SELECT Id, Custom_Field_1__c FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Custom_Field_2 = 'Value' AND Custom_Field__c > 0];
```

I have a custom field on Opportunities and I want to see if it's value matches a value of Custom_Field_1__c from this list. I've spent a fair amount of time looking around but am still stumped. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using a list you could put the values of Custom_Field_1__c into a set.

then when you do a compare you can use a method called contains.

```
set<string> myset = new set<string>(); 
For(Custom_Object__c m :mylist){ 
    myset.add(m.custom_field_1__c); 
} 

for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new) {
    myset.contains(o.Fieldvalue__c); //returns true/false
}
```

Comment: I need to convert the SOQL results, a list of sobjects, to set of strings (the value of Custom_Field_1__c). Can this be done?

Comment: You could iterate through your list of sobjects to populate the set.
set<string> myset = new set<string>();
For(Custom_Object__c m :mylist){
    myset.add(m.custom_field_1__c);
}
Then you can do MySet.contains('Comparison_String');

Comment: Yo, Brian, I took the liberty of moving your code from the comment into the answer. I still don't have the rep to edit without peer review, so if someone wants to take a look, feel free to approve or reject. :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much to both of you!

Comment: Peter - well that was a good idea:) Thank you for moving it.